# Certificate (pfx file) works in code but not working after Hosting from ASP Net web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have to verify the `pfx` file and get certificate details from the web base application 
but its not working after hosting the page in `IIS`, It only work on single machine.

-First I create an exe for the fetching the details but still its not working,

(exe saves the response in one table.
And we want to fetch the response in the web Application.
It is working through Code But After Hosting this is not working.)

I am fetching the data through creating the batch files.

like :

Please give me any suggestion or Idea for how to get the data from exe to web application.
can any one have idea please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate loading in .NET is tied to the user profile and certificate store - even though the certificate is loaded from file. When loading in a hosting environment some special flags need to be added:

```
// The X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet flag is required when loading a
// certificate from file on a shared hosting solution such as Azure.
private static readonly X509Certificate2 signingCertificate =
  new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
  "~\\App_Data\\Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp.pfx"), "",
  X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Exampel from https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp/Models/AssertionModel.cs